# Can sonar build java 6 and java 7 projects on a single server?

Tags: sonarqube

We have a server that runs Sonar and previously only had Java 6 installed and everything worked fine.  We now have a Java 7 project and are encountering the "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" version when the Maven surefire plugin tries to analyze the project.

Is there a way to specify the Java version sonar should use for a specific project?

Java 7 is already installed on the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meet this case too. Now setup two sonarqube instances for different java version projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind found the JDK option under Advanced in the Jenkins configuration for the job.